# No message serializer has been configured

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3, nservicebus4

Upgrading from version 3 of nservicebus to version 4, and receiving the following error message

> "No message serializer has been configured."

stack trace:

at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.ValidateConfiguration() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 866
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Start(Action startupAction) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 739
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Start() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 718
   at CycleMonkey.Inventory.CreateOrder.IT_OPS.CustomInit.Init() in d:\dev\backup\soa_cyclemonkey\Inventory\Inventory.CreateOrder\IT_OPS\CustomInit.cs:line 20
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Configuration.ConfigManager.ConfigureCustomInitAndStartup() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Hosting\Configuration\ConfigurationManager.cs:line 43
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.PerformConfiguration() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Hosting\GenericHost.cs:line 126
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Hosting\GenericHost.cs:line 29
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost.Start() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\WindowsHost.cs:line 56
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_5(WindowsHost service) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\Program.cs:line 76
   at Topshelf.Internal.ControllerDelegates`1.StartActionObject(Object obj) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ControllerDelegates.cs:line 18
   at Topshelf.Internal.IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper`1.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_1(TService service) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper.cs:line 65
   at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1.<.cctor>b__1(ServiceController`1 sc) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceController.cs:line 35
   at Magnum.StateMachine.LambdaAction`1.Execute(T instance, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0

Has something been missed in the upgrade? Version 3 of code that was working :

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server
{
}

public class CustomInit : IWantCustomInitialization
    {
                    public void Init()
        {
            Configure.Instance
                     .CastleWindsorBuilder()
                     .DefaultBuilder()
                     .Sagas()
                     .RunTimeoutManagerWithInMemoryPersistence()
                     .ConfigureMongoSagaPersister<CreateOrderSagaData>("mongodb://localhost/create-order");

            Configure.Instance
                     .XmlSerializer()
                     .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                     .MsmqTransport()
                     .UnicastBus();

        }
    }
```

Version 4 of the same code with the suggested changes required with the upgrade

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, UsingTransport<Msmq>
{
}

public class CustomInit : IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            Configure.Features.Enable<Sagas>();
            Configure.Serialization.Xml();

            Configure.Instance
               .CastleWindsorBuilder()
               .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
               .ConfigureMongoSagaPersister<CreateOrderSagaData>("mongodb://localhost/create-order");

            Configure.Instance
                    .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                    .UnicastBus()
                    .CreateBus()
                    .Start();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the calls to CreateBus and Start - those don't belong in IWantCustomInitialization.

Comment: Also `IConfigureThisEndpoint` and `IWantCustomInitialization` should be the same class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When bootstrapping a different container, use the IWantCustomInitialization interface together with the IConfigureThisEndpoint like @JohnSimons mentioned.

Also, when you are implementing the IWantCustomInitialization in the IConfigureThisEndpoint, there is no bus yet, so an instance has not been created at this point, so you'd need to use Configure.With() instead of Configure.Instance.

NOTE: You don't need to specify UsingTransport as Msmq is the default transport.
You also don't need to specify Configure.Serialization.Xml() as Xml is the default serializer.

So, if you change your code to something like below, it should work:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Features.Enable<Sagas>();

        Configure.With()
            .CastleWindsorBuilder()
            .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
            .MsmqSubscriptionStorage();

    }
}
```